# Rxjava with Retrofit save emit data in file in background

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I am very new to Rxjava and RetroFit. I have one issue .

I am fetching data from server with below code.

```
 ApiUtils.getMainRestService(mContext).getMain(url).
            subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
            subscribe(new Action1<CMSMain>() {
                @Override
                public void call(CMSMain CMSMain) {

                }
            });
```

Now i want to save this CMSMain into file in background . How can i do this.
yes i can use Schedular.newThread() inside observerOn method after that which method will call in UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get result immediately and save to file in background, use:

```
ApiUtils.getMainRestService(mContext).getMain(url)
    .map(new Func1<CMSMain, CMSMain>() {
        @Override
        public CMSMain call(final CMSMain cmsMain) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    saveToFile(cmsMain);
                }
            }).start();
            return cmsMain;
        }
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Action1<CMSMain>() {
        @Override
        public void call(CMSMain CMSMain) {

        }
    });
```